# TYPO3 6.0.0 error: trying to access a folder in a storage that is not browsable

Tags: php, web, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

I've downloaded the introduction package for TYPO3 6.0.0rc1 and tried to
use a new file storage named "fileuser". So I created an new file
storage entry with the relative base path "fileuser/" and created the
folder in filesystem (permission is set to 777) along with the
"*processed*" folder (also defined in the file storage dataset).

Now i called the File -> Filelist module and reloaded the folder tree.
The new file storage is shown but with the addition "offline". If I try
to access it I am getting the error: "You are trying to access a folder
in a storage that is not browsable.".

Any idea on how to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common problem when developing within a distributed development environment with separate working copies. Any changes made to the file/folder structure should be adopted immediately by all other working copies.

As pgampe has pointed out, the storage folder must be set online (again). This is how you do it step by step:

1. In the admin panel, select the "List" View under "Web"
2. Select the root page in the page tree (should have the typo icon assigned to it)
3. In the edit area that loads, now edit your storage folder under the data tab "Filestorage" by clicking on the pencil symbol.
4. Select the "Access" tab
5. Activate the "online" checkbox.
6. Save your entry

Your storage folder now should be accessable again.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the `online` checkbox in the `storage configuration record` on the `access tab`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry for my being newbie on typo3, I can't find the online flag configuration anywhere, would you please give me some more hint on this?

Comment: You need to edit the storage configuration record on the root of your pagetree. It as a tab access and there is a checkbox for online.